# @KafkaListener method not work with spring @Profile annotation

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 2 @KafkaListener  methods listening on the same tipic *TopicA*,

but they are also annotated with different @Profile("dev") and @Profile("prod"),

I set *spring.profiles.active=dev* ,and send messages to TopicA, both 2 methods can consume the message.

is it a known bug for @KafkaListener with @Profile ? or there are something wrong with my config ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, because `@KafkaListener` doesn't present a bean. The `@Profile` can restrict only beans - factory methods in the `@Configuration` classes or scanned `@Service`s: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles-java

So, what you need is like distribution those methods to different classes and move `@Profile` to their bean definition level.